# python 2.7 getter and setter not working WITH inheritance from object

Tags: python, object, setter, getter

```
class EditImage(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._image = None
        self._imageName = ''

    @property
    def image(self):
        return self._image

    @property
    def imageName(self):
        return self._imageName

    @image.setter
    def image(self, filePath):
        self._image = Image.open(filePath)

    @imageName.setter
    def imageName(self,image):
        self._imageName = self.image.fileName
```

Then

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ei = EditImage()
    images = importImages("D:\\imgs")
    for name in images:
        ei.image(name)
```

and I get the error:

```
    ei.image(name)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

With debugging I see it goes to the getter not to the setter, it calls `ei.image()`
The class inherits from `object`, still it doesn't work. 
What am I missing here?
Thank you!

Comment: Try `ei.image = name`

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I didn't expect ppl to run this code here, so I didn't pay attention to the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a property, you have to use assignment instead of parenthesis:

```
ei.image = name
```

You get a `TypeError: NoneType` because `ei.image` returns the value of the *image* property of your *ei* object which is None at this moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ei.image
```

for getting value of `image`

as its a property and its `getter` method is overwritten.And

it would be

```
ei.image = name
```

for setting value of `image`.

As these are now properties you cant make a `function call` over it

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed myself. I expected it to work in the java way, something like

```
ei.setImage(name)
```

Python way:

```
class ClassEnc(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 0

    @property
        def x(self):
        print "getter"
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,val):
        print "setter"
        self.__x = val


obj = ClassEnc()
obj.x = 3
obj.x(2)
```

result:

```
setter
getter
getter
    obj.x(2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Java way:

```
public class ClassEnc {

private int x;

public int getX() {
    System.out.println("getter");
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    System.out.println("setter");
    this.x = x;
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
}
```

}

```
public class maincl {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassEnc ce = new ClassEnc();
    ce.getX();
    ce.setX(34);
}
```

}

result:

```
getter
x = 0
setter
x = 34
```